# Can't connect to Strato instance on Azure

Tags: blockapps, microsoft-azure

I set up a Blockapps Strato instance on Azure according to [these instructions](http://www.blockapps.net/dashboard/quick-starts/azure) but I can't actually connect to it. The "connect" button is grayed out (despite setting it up with a static public ip address) and there's no DNS name to let me SSH into it. Can anyone help?